# Telnet - how to verify why a port is blocked?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, telnet, port

We have linux machines with RedHat 6.5 operating system.

When we try to telnet to localhost on port 8182, we get connection refused:

```
service iptables status
Firewall is not running

telnet localhost  8182
Connection refused

cat /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=DISABLED
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Any suggestion on how to find the *reason* that we get connection refused 
even if the firewall is down and selinux is disabled

Comment: There is no service listening on port 8182.

Comment: how to verify which service should listening to port 8182

Comment: Can I ask what is giving you the idea that something should be listening on that port? Why did you pick that port in particular?

Comment: on other machine , port 8182 is listening , but on other same machine its not listening

Comment: Apparently port 8182 is used for vmware fault domain manager. Do you have vmware installed on the other PC?

Comment: both machines are VM machines

Comment: `netstat -tulpn` will list all processes and the ports they're listening on.

Comment: yes but if I do - netstat -tulpn | grep 8182
 , then I see that no proccess is hold this port

Comment: Which is why you're getting connection refused when you try to telnet.

Comment: yes this is also my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when we do telnet to localhost on port 8182 , we get connection refuse

This means that there's nothing running on port 8182 on the machine. Check that the service supposed to run on that port is installed and running. ([TCP/UDP 8182 is usually used for the VMware Fault Domain Manager.)](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/ports08000.htm)

On a side note, you do not need to open ports on the firewall or disable it for connections from localhost to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting connection refused there is either no service listening on port 8182 on your loopback ip address, or there is a firewall in the way.

You can verify what processes are listing on which ip/ports using `netstat`:

```
netstat -tunlp
```

Where `t` is `tcp`, `u` is `udp`, `n` is show ip and port numbers rather than names, `l` is listening and `p` is show the process.

You can verify if there is a firewall in the way by using iptables:

```
iptables -nvL
```

Comment: OP already verified that the firewall is disabled, and firewalls don't block local connections anyway.